# Species/Race lifespans

Tags: biology, anatomy, longevity

What are all the factors of a species' or race's lifespan, scientifically? Know that I am not asking for life expectancy, which can obviously be handled by the worldbuilder him/herself, but rather lifespan in a controlled environment, which is less able to be simply chosen.

To better phrase the question then; what are the biological factors to an organism's natural lifespan in a controlled environment? Life expectancy is a much more complex thing that we should avoid getting into for now. Let's also ignore any cultural factors and say that scientific and medical advancement has helped the species or race reach its natural lifespan before it eventually dies from an age-dependent death.

The types of factors I'm looking for are in regards to their biochemistry, their anatomy, and so on.

Comment: Are you asking for the factors of an individual's lifespan relative to their species? Or what determines lifespan of a species on average?

Comment: certain proteins which are important when responding to DNA damages other than that eat your greens I supposes...

Comment: Actually it's not a duplicate, it's the same question with a different title.

Comment: Your question is scientifically imponderable. While there are some factors that are indicative of influencing lifespan, nobody really knows. if this question could be answered here, that person should be in the running for a Nobel Prize. There is no easy answer to the question of what determines lifespan.

Comment: Since nobody has mentioned this yet: if your question is put on hold, you should edit it to try and address the reasons for its closure and the feedback from user comments. You should **not** just re-post the exact same question and hope it won't get put on hold a second time.

Answer (score 2):

In any species, faster metabolism means shorter lifespan. 
Faster metabolism is association with faster motion, and faster motion often is associated with smaller size. So larger and slower species will live longer.

here is some examples: https://www.britannica.com/science/life-span

Answer (score 1):

Lobsters are biologically immortal. They have amazing cellular replication.

However they do not live forever in practice, because once they get above a certain size molting kills them as it takes to much energy and time.

This aplies to your species as well,  they need to be biologically immortal ( have good telmorane repair methods ) .

And they need to have a shut off switch to turn off their growth so they don't die from growing larger then their physiology can support.